# What thread pool wcf uses when usesynchronizationcontext=false

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I have a wcf client I generated using SVCUTIL with the /async flag.

The server is syncronic, but I only use the Begin/End methods in my client.

Also, I added the attribute UseSynchronizationContext=false in the CallbackBehavior.

My question is: How does WCF work with threads in this mode?
Or better phrased - Is WCF using the ThreadPool class to acquire new threads for the callback when I call simultanous functions? Or does it have some custom implementation?

I Googled the subject for hours, didn't find anything near an answer.

EDIT: I see I've been a little unclear here - I'm not asking about the server app, I'm asking about the client app - how does it manage the threads on which it returns the callbacks when I set the usesynchronizationcontext flag to false?

Comment: The fact that your client is async has no bearing at all on threading at the service end

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear - I'm asking what happens in the client side.
The server side is code that is unreachable to me and basically I don't care too much about it.

Answer (score 1):

Your service's threading is unaffected by how the client calls it. When you use proxy Begin/End methods, the proxy is using a different client thread to make the service call so that your application code does not block.

With .NET 4.5 task based asynchronous calls are now preferred.

See [Synchronous and Asynchronous Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx) for an overview of the different patterns.

Comment: I'm the client in the scanario, and I'm asking about the client app - how does it manage the threading using the characteristics I described.

About the .NET 4.5 - I'm developing on WIN XP .NET4, and we can just decide to upgrade all our software to a higher .NET version.